# How to put many If else statements in return

Tags: python-3.x

Im curious if there is a way to execute code like this:

**in array  we have True and False statements in op we have 'AND' or  'OR' 
  or 'XOR'**

```
def logical_calc(array, op):

    if array.count(False)<1 and op=="AND":
        return 1

    elif array.count(True)>0 and  op=='OR':
        return 1
    elif  array.count(True)%2!=0 and op=='XOR':
        return 1
     else: 
        return 0
```

in this way:

```
def logical_calc(array, op):
return True if  array.count(False)<1 and op=="AND"
       elif array.count(True)>0      and op=='OR' 
       elif array.count(True)%2!=0   and op=='XOR'
```

only in return statement

Comment: you should give the equivalent example without the return statement, it is not clear what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: To clarify: you want to return `true` if `array.count(False)<1 and op=="AND"`, but what do you want to do in the `elif` cases?

Comment: yes this is what i want to do

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to return True if any one of the 3 conditions is True, to achieve this you eliminate the if statements completely and write your return value as a boolean expression;

```
def logical_calc(array, op):
  return (array.count(False)<1 and op=="AND") or 
         (array.count(True)>0 and op=='OR') or   
         (array.count(True)%2!=0   and op=='XOR')
```